# Is it possible to have a script that double quotes a view or proc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scripting

I apparently cannot figure out the key words to google search for what I want, so I need help finding out how to do this. I feel like this may be a duplicate, but I just cannot find this anywhere else.

I would like to be able to easily save a bunch of create table/view/proc scripts to a file. The file has an easy-to-execute format that will drop and then re-create all of the objects, so it can be run on multiple databases.

This format works well for me as I have to make changes to some objects during development, and then make the same changes on multiple other databases. I can just change the database and click execute.

However, some of the scripts have A LOT of quotes in them, and it gets QUITE annoying to have to double/quad quote them every time I make a change or add a new object to the file. For instance...

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE NAME = 'MF1' AND schema_id = (SELECT schema_id FROM sys.schemas WHERE NAME = 'CFConversion'))
BEGIN

EXEC('CREATE VIEW [CFConversion].[MF1]
AS
...
...
...
CROSS APPLY (
VALUES (''T'', ''FIT', FIT, '''')
      ,(''T'', ''SIT', SIT, '''')
      ,(''T'', ''FUTA', FUTA, '''')
      ,(''T'', ''Employee_SUI'', EMPLOYEE_SUI, '''')
      ,(''T'', ''Employee_SDI'', EMPLOYEE_SDI, '''')
...
...
...
```

With tons of values in the Cross Apply, it just gets annoying. How can I easily export the definition of an object to have double/quad quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS, you can check the option "Check for object existence" in Tools/Options/SQL Server Object Explorer/Scripting/Object Scripting options.

When you then script for CREATE from the Object Explorer, SSMS will script the object as an sp_executesql statement, fully double-quoted.

Comment: Fantastic! Didn't know that existed.

Comment: Is this known to be buggy? Worked fine the other day, but trying to do it on a SP now and it is not behaving. It is putting the check for object in there, but not double quoting as desired in a sp_executesql

Comment: I don't think it's buggy but I may not have noticed that it seems to work differently depending on the object being scripted

Comment: Have you tried using the "Modify" option instead of "script as create"? That works for me on SPs with the "Check for object existence" checked.

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone else, an alternative approach to the using double single-quotes to represent a single single-quote in a string is `CHAR(39)`.  That sentence is hard to follow, so as an example:

`'Don''t'`

can be represented using this approach as

`'Don' + CHAR(39) + 't'`

While this may not look as pretty with quick strings, it may clear up issues with large blocks of DSQL.  To further clean it up, I also suggest you mask special characters with variables such as:

```
DECLARE @tick CHAR(1) = CHAR(39)
SELECT 'Don' + @tick + 't code with DSQL'
```

In my scripts that I want to keep clean, I often take this approach with Tabs `CHAR(9)` and newline (crlf) characters `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're pulling the data out in a query, then `REPLACE(<value>, '''', '''''')` should work quite nicely.

UPDATE: Edit correcting my mistake (have to double-up the single quotes in the double quotes) actually provided by @Steven Hibble.